# Excel VBA Macro to create PIVOT Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to create a VBA Macro code to create a Pivot table showing in the image below.

[image]

In the report filter I have Aircraft type and in Column Level I have Area and summation value I have Count of Aircraft type.

I record a macro after creating this table but after run the macro I was not be able to create the Pivot showing in my image. I am new here so I am unable to findout how to resolve this issue?

My code is given below:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:B16").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet13!R1C1:R16C2", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet14!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable4", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion12
    Sheets("Sheet14").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Aircraft Type")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Area")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable4").PivotFields("Aircraft Type"), "Count of Aircraft Type", xlCount
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you think it might be easier if you got started by simply recording yourself creating said pivot table and then attempting to modify the code to suit your purposes? Seems a little more efficient than expecting everyone else to retype your data from a static image and then write your code for you.

Comment: Can you post the code you do have? Is it code that creates the table, or code you ran *after* it's created?

Comment: @BruceWayne: I have edited my code..Please find it above..and this is the code to create table..But unfortunately I am not be able to create it